# Not able to pass "+" to grails webservice URL

Tags: url, grails, decode, parameters

We are having an issue when we pass a parameter having "+" character in it, to a webservice (written in groovy), the character is being decoded to a space. Even if we pass "%2B", it is being decoded twice(?) and resulting in to a space. We are using grails  1.3.6

Can some one help me out?

URLMappings file has

```
"/actionName/${param1}"(controller:'myController', action:'myAction')
```

When we call

```
/actionName/my+param
```

or

```
/actionName/my%2Bparam
```

both result in to

```
/actionName/my param
```

Thanks,
Madhu.

Comment: That URLMapping looks off.  Are you sure it shouldn't be "/actionName/$param1"(controller:"myController", action:"myAction").  Note the $ to denote that param1 is a variable.  Not saying that fixes your issue, but better to be as accurate as possible with your question.

Comment: How are you doing the actual call?

Comment: did you try `/actionName/my%252Bparam` (% also escaped)

Comment: Yes, That resulted in to "my%2Bparam"

Comment: I think this is a bug then to be reported.

Answer (score 0):

"/actionName/$param1?"(controller: "actionController", action: "actionName")

and then access it like that...

```
http://localhost:8383/app/actionName/foo+bar
```